# MVC pagedlist.mvc and aspx view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nuget, pagedlist

I have got a page where im using the Nuget package pagedlist.mvc 3.0.18 (The latest version for MVC3). The problem is that when i'm listing the pages its makes my pages into a list of  which look like

previous

1

2

3

4

next

Instead of < 1,2,3,4,5,6,7.. >

My view looks like

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IPagedList<News>>" %>
<%@ Import namespace="PagedList" %>
<%@ Import namespace="PagedList.Mvc" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

 <table>
 <tr>
 <td>
<% foreach (var v in Model)
   {%>

    <%: v.Content %><br />
    <%: v.DateCreated %><br />
    <%: v.Email %><br />

<%} %>

<h2>News</h2>

<%: Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("News", new { page }), PagedListRenderOptions.Minimal)%>
```

Code behind looks like

```
public ActionResult News(int? page)
        {
            List<News> products = HomeBLL.GetNewsList(); //returns IQueryable<Product> representing an unknown number of products. a thousand maybe?

            var pageNumber =  page ?? 1; // if no page was specified in the querystring, default to the first page (1)
            var onePageOfProducts = products.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 25); // will only contain 25 products max because of the pageSize

            ViewBag.OnePageOfProducts = onePageOfProducts;

            return View(onePageOfProducts);
        }
```

Any suggestions on what could be wrong? The standard CSS is included as well.

Comment: Well it seems to be a problem with the aspx code. This version and others doesn't seem to work with this plugin. Changed to Razor and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the newest package of pagedlist is NOT supported for the aspx views, unless you reach a low level of this package.

Answer (score 0):

You should include PagedList.css in your View (it is located in Content folder).

Answer (score 0):

Include the css file PagedList.css inside HEAD tags in your _Layout page or at the top of your viewpage.